# sorting using the Spring pagedListHolder

Tags: java, sorting, spring-mvc, pagination

I have implemented pagination on an MVC page using the Spring PagedListHolder bean.  All is well for page size and paging but I am struggling with the sort.  I'm guessing that I am completely missing the point as my code makes no difference at all and I've struggled to find much documentation that I really understand.  A simple version of the code is below.  It doesn't fail but it doesn't do anything (I was going to get it to work and then start modifying it to use more than one field) .

Essentially the BookBean has a number of fields - Id, Title, Author, YearPublished etc.

```
 //Load getBooks() into a list as it returns a Set
 List <BookBean> booklist = new ArrayList <BookBean>(getBooks());

 PagedListHolder <BookBean> pagedListHolder = new PagedListHolder<BookBean> (booklist);

 MutableSortDefinition x = new MutableSortDefinition ("title", true, true);
 pagedListHolder.setSort(x);
```

I assumed that the PagedListHolder bean would do implement the sort for me but it does nothing.  I can't work out if this is because I am not defining and implementing the sort definition properly or because I'm expecting too much from it.  There is no Comparator implementation in the BookBean object.  I guess this is what I would need to do if I wanted to do the sort myself and not bother with the PagedListHolder sorting.

Can anyone tell me if there is a way I can do the sorting in the PagedListHolder without implementing the Comparator interface or is this why the above code isn't sorting by title ?

Many thanks.

Comment: It seems like this should work.  as long as "title" is really a property on the BookBean class.  Have you tried implementing SortDefinition rather than use MutableSortableDefinition?

Comment: You also may need to actually dall "doSort()" on the PagedListHolder object

Comment: Many thanks.  The 2nd comment made me look again.  I saw doSort() in the documentation but it is hidden from the implementation so I assumed it was not necessary.  I guess there is an initial default sort even if it is null and what was required was resort().  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think doSort() may have been deprecated (?) but the method reSort() actions the sort.  Many thanks.